# MATLAB minreal for stabilizing a control plan

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, control-theory

Having weighing matrices `G` and `Rin` using `lqry`

```
  [K,~,~] = lqry(mysys,G,Rin);
```

I got the following error:

```
  Error using ss/lqry (line 96)   The "lqry" command failed to stabilize the plant or find an optimal feedback gain. To remedy this problem:
  1. Make sure that all unstable poles of A are controllable through B (use MINREAL to check)
  2. Modify the weights Q and R to make [C D;0 I]'*[Q N;N' R]*[C D;0 I] positive definite (use EIG to check positivity).
```

If I want to use `minreal` for stabilizing the plan, how should I modify `G` and `Rin` ?

```
  mysys=minreal(mysys);
  G=?????
  Rin=?????
  [K,~,~] = lqry(mysys,G,Rin);
```

Comment: any of idea from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If your state representation is nonminimal and after passing through `minreal` some of the states are removed, then your `Q` and if you are using `N` matrix needs to comply with the new size.

Say you have a 2x2 system. If you had initially 5 states and you would have a 5x5 Q matrix, 2x2 R matrix and if you are using 3x2 N matrix.

Then suppose two of these states are removed after `minreal`. In that case the Q matrix would be 3x3, ,if you are using, N must be 3x2 for the new system.